How to use RequestBody Annotation of Swagger 3 correctly?
I want to have a description for RequestBody in Swagger API documentation, so I make my login method like this:
@PostMapping("/login")
@PermitAll
@Operation(summary = "login by username and password")
@OperateLog(enable = false)
public CommonResult<AuthLoginRespVO> login(
    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(description = "login request body", required = true,content = @Content(schema=@Schema(implementation = AuthLoginReqVO.class)))
    @RequestBody @Valid AuthLoginReqVO reqVO){
    return success(authService.login(reqVO));
}

and the request entity like this:
@Schema(description = "")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class AuthLoginReqVO {

    @Schema(description = "username", required = true, example = "admin")
    @NotEmpty(message = "...")
    @Length(min = 4, max = 16, message = "...")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", message = "...")
    private String username;

    @Schema(description = "password", required = true, example = "123456")
    @NotEmpty(message = "...")
    @Length(min = 4, max = 16, message = "...")
    private String password;

The username and the password should have described as request body (JSON) in Swagger, but now they appear both in parameters and request body.

I found only this question and used @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody as the answer mentioned, but parameters are still generated in the documentation.
If I remove @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody, only parameters are generated in the documentation.
I'm wondering if something like configurations or processors associated with Swagger are affecting the result, so I searched some keywords in the project globally, but found nothing useful.
I'm not quite familiar with this project because it's just an open-source project.
I expect some directions to check this problem.

It should work without  @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody.

Everything seems fine. I would advice you to try another version of SpringDoc OpenAPI dependency, if it doesn't help, try to check Jackson ObjectMapper's settings or Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer, maybe you have some custom serialize settings that make effect on generated documentation
